# Issue while referencing a .Net framework library in .Net Standard class library

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-standard

I have a .Net Standard 1.4 class library named "StandardLib"
I also have a .Net framework 4.5.2 class library named "FrameworkLib"

In StandardLib I added reference to FrameworkLib.

I got below error

**Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. StandardLib C:\Users\Monu\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\StandardLib\StandardLib\Class1.cs**

The below post in .Net Standard github page says we should add reference of non standard library via nuget. I am not finding a mscorlib nuget package.

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md#assembly-unification

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reply from GitHub community of .Net Standard

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/223